# Can't change style of canvas text

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to change the default font style of the canvas text to [Press Start 2P](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Press+Start+2P)

I have imported the url into a css file like so

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');

.canvasClass{
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
}
```

```
<Box className='canvasClass'>
<Canvas2/>
</Box>
```

and im trying to draw some text like this:

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(194,213,219,0.8)'
context.font = "42px Press Start 2P";
context.textAlign = 'center'
```

I can confirm that the font is being applied to the parent div, however I cannot apply my desired font to the canvas that is inside that div. Why would I have trouble applying the font to the canvas if it works with other text components in the same div?

EDIT:

I would like to add that I change font to Roboto (I'm assuming another Google font)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the font family name in quotes like you did in your CSS declaration.

```js
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(194,213,219,0.8)'
context.font = "42px 'Press Start 2P'";
context.textAlign = 'center'
```

Also, wait for `document.fonts.ready` to be sure the external font has been loaded before you use it in your canvas.

```js
(async () => {
  await document.fonts.ready;
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(194,213,219,0.8)'
  context.font = "42px 'Press Start 2P'";
  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.textBaseline = 'middle';
  context.fillText('Hello world', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');

.canvasClass{
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
}
```

```html
<div class=canvasClass>
  <canvas width=500 height=150></canvas>
</div>
```